# Joining 2 large relations in Rascal

Tags: rascal

I'm trying to join two relations in Rascal, much like a SQL join, with the following code:

```
rel[loc,loc,loc] methodInvocationsWithClass = {arround 40000 tuples};
rel[loc,loc] declaredClassHierarchy = {around 20000 tuples};

{ <from,to,class,super> | <from,to,class> <- methodInvocationsWithClass, <sub,super> <- declaredClassHierarchy, class == sub };
```

While this does exactly what I need it appears it only works well on small relations and doesn't scale well.

Is there perhaps a more efficient alternative way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 1):

Indeed, we have the [join keyword](http://tutor.rascal-mpl.org/Rascal/Expressions/Values/Relation/Join/Join.html) for this. Also lots of other [useful relational operations are supported](http://tutor.rascal-mpl.org/Rascal/Expressions/Values/Relation/Relation.html). Either by keywords or functions inside the [Relation](http://tutor.rascal-mpl.org/Rascal/Libraries/Prelude/Relation/Relation.html) module.

Comment: If I understand the join keyword correctly, is returns a sort of Cartesian product of the two relations. But I need to match the tuples on specific values, hence the 'class == sub' equation. I could try something like this

{ <from,to,class,super> | <from,to,class,sub,super> <- methodInvocationsWithClass join declaredClassHierarchy, class == sub };

But unfortunately that doesn't perform either for these numbers. I suspect it will first create a new relation of 40.000  * 20.000 tuples before filtering out those who does not match the specified filter.